# MSBuild what is correct way to run target with wanted working directory?

Tags: msbuild

I am converting a big NMake project into MSBuild projects. This is my first time using MSBuild so a lot of questions. First of all, how do I change working directory when calling different projects?

I have a top-level A.proj, which import solution wide properties at the beginning. It is in dir C:\SomeFolder. Then, I want it to build project B and others which are in C:\SomeFolder\Sub. Proj B are written to treat its own dir as root dir for file read\write. But in my new setup, MSBuild treat A.proj's dir as working directory so all sub projects fail to get right files of their own.

How do I correctly do this?

Comment: You _can_ get a working directory, but that's probably not what you actually want.  There are [built-in variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx) such as `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)`, that may be more useful to you.

Comment: How are you invoking project B from A? The way you describe it is how it should work. Relative paths inside a project file should be relative to that file, not the calling file.

Comment: @Andrew in your link, I see example in MSBuildProjectDirectory that, in the target, it calls MSBuild on all sub-projects. Do these MSBuild cmds then run in parallel if /m is given?

Comment: @Sheen, you might be looking for the [BuildInParallel parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651793.aspx), although i've never tested it myself... it seems from the description that the default value is true.